# emulator stopped working in eclipse

Tags: android-emulator

```
[2012-07-10 07:11:32 - imageview] Android Launch!
[2012-07-10 07:11:32 - imageview] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2012-07-10 07:11:32 - imageview] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2012-07-10 07:11:32 - imageview] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'F:\android\android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk_r12-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

it was working fine yesterday..but now not working.i have deleted previous one and created new emulators.they are also not working,giving same error as above.please help me out.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to task manager-> processes and end the process "adb.exe".
Close your emulator and eclipse and restart. It will work fine.